# Trigger is not created in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm building a database for a library management system, so I have created three tables: books, members and borrow(describe the relation between the two tables).
for each book I store in the books table, I store it's quantity.
for each member that want to borrow a book, I store his id and the book id in the borrow table.
for every time a member want to borrow a book, I want to check that borrowed quantity is equal or less than the quantity stored for that book in the books table(in case it was more it will rise an error and will not accept the new data) , so I tried to achieve this using a trigger
the problem is that when I try to run the trigger it's not created, and it does not even give an error message, when I try even to see the trigger that is created in the database using the command:(select name from sqlite_master where type = 'trigger';) it does not show any thing

here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE books(
book_id INTEGER CHECK (book_id>0999) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
book_title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
author_name VARCHAR(20),
quantity INT NOT NULL,
genre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
book_place VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(book_title,author_name)
);

CREATE TABLE members(
member_id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT CHECK(member_id<1000) , 
member_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
member_phone TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE 
CHECK (LENGTH(member_phone)==11 AND member_phone NOT GLOB '*[^0-9]*'
AND (SUBSTR(member_phone,1,3)=='010' OR SUBSTR(member_phone,1,3)=='011' 
OR SUBSTR(member_phone,1,3)=='012' OR SUBSTR(member_phone,1,3)=='015' )),
sub_startDate TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(sub_startDate IS DATE(sub_startDate)),
sub_endDate TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(sub_endDate IS DATE(sub_endDate)) 
);





CREATE TABLE borrow(
member_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
book_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
borrowed_date TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(borrowed_date IS DATE(borrowed_date)),
return_date TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (return_date IS DATE(return_date)),
FOREIGN KEY(member_id) REFERENCES members(member_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ,
FOREIGN KEY(book_id) REFERENCES books(book_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(member_id,book_id)
);



CREATE TRIGGER not_enough_copies
BEFORE INSERT, UPDATE 
ON borrow
WHEN 
(SELECT((SELECT 
COUNT(*) 
FROM borrow
WHERE book_id=NEW.book_id)
NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 
(SELECT quantity FROM books WHERE books.book_id==NEW.book_id)))
BEGIN
RAISE(ABORT,'ERROR!..This book is not available in the library right now')   
END;
```

Comment: I would total appreciate if someone response quickly as possible

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have done as you said, but it was sill not created. and it's not just the trigger I posted here that is not created, I have tried much simpler triggers (including triggers that I have copied from internet), and the triggers just seems not to be created. As I have already mentioned there no kind of message appear (not even an error message)

Comment: Take some time to read about triggers in SQLite: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/ and https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: @forpas,thank you so much for you reply, I have already seen the article you have referred to, but the problem is that any kind of trigger(including triggers that I just copied from the internet ) doesn't seem to be created, I don't know where the problem is. I have thought that I might have disabled creating a trigger in the database somehow without me noticing. So I wanted to know if there is a way to enable creating a trigger in the database (or any other solution that works)

Comment: You can't expect any trigger from the internet to work in your database. The trigger that you have in your question is syntactically wrong. This is why I posted the 2 links in my previous comment.

Comment: @forpas. please, bear with me. I have exactly copied the leads table and (validate_email_before_insert_leads) trigger from the link you referred to (sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger ). still, the trigger wasn't created and if I try to execute any command after the trigger for example (select * from leads;) the command is not executed

Comment: Where are you executing these statements?

Comment: @forpas, I'm using visual studio code

Comment: I don't know how you can interact with a SQLite db with Visual Studio Code. Download a tool like DB Browsr for SQLite and try with that.

Comment: @forpas,thank you very much, sir. I have tried running it from the command window and it worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.